# How to convert RepeatBehavior.Forever to 2x in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Follow code:

**C#:**

```
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = -1200,
    To = 1200,
    RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever, //here convert forever to 2x
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};

tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);
```

**XAML:**

```
<DoubleAnimation 
  RepeatBehavior="2x"/>
```

In the xaml file, I just set the 2x value, how can I do this in C#?

I took this example:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753367(v=vs.100).aspx

I want to convert "`RepeatBehavior.Forever`" to 2x, any solution?

Comment: New repeatbehavior(2) ?...the forever is a static property returning an instance...but there's normal constructors there to create your own object

Comment: @Ctznkane525, thank you :)

Comment: I'd also guess casting a string of 2x to the class repeatbehavior might work... assuming repeatbehavior class has a converter

Comment: @Ctznkane525, How to execute a function after 2x finish?

Comment: Separate question should be a new question

Comment: @Ctznkane525, please check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48966705/how-to-execute-a-function-after-2x-finish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **C#:**

```
story.RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2.0);
```

try:

```
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
{
    From = -1200,
    To = 1200,
    RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2.0), //the number must be double
    Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)
};
```