# How to execute a function after '"new RepeatBehavior(2)" finish?

Tags: c#, wpf

Follow code:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="Wpf_Notice.MostrarAviso"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpf_Notice"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Notice Show" Height="300" Width="300" WindowStyle="None" ShowInTaskbar="False" ResizeMode="NoResize" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <!--...-->
        </StackPanel>
        <Canvas Background="Black" >
            <Canvas Canvas.Bottom="0" ClipToBounds="True" Name="canMain" Background="Red" Height="97" Width="300">
                <TextBlock FontSize="70" Name="tbmarquee" Height="74" FontFamily="Arial Black" Foreground="White" Canvas.Top="10"></TextBlock>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    canMain.Width = ActualWidth;
    tbmarquee.Text = "Donald Trump announced on Friday a new package of measures against North Korea...";
    UpdateLayout();

    DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = -tbmarquee.ActualWidth,
        To = canMain.ActualWidth,
        RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior(2),
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    };

    tbmarquee.BeginAnimation(Canvas.RightProperty, doubleAnimation);

    WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    Topmost = true;
}
```

The code above shows a right-to-left news, using the class "DoubleAnimation", after passing 2 news `RepeatBehavior = new RepeatBehavior (2)`, call a function to hide the news.

How can I call a function after passing 2 news items?

Any solution ?

Comment: @FrancescoB. Can you give me an example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect to [Completed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed(v=vs.110).aspx) event and do whatever you need to do from there.

```
DoubleAnimation doubleAnimation = //...
doubleAnimation.Completed += (s, e) => MyFunction();
```

Comment: How to add `Completed` in C# ?